# How to generate GA for http (main domain) and and https (sub domain)?

Tags: http, https, google-analytics

I am having main domain (`http://example.com`) and a sub-domain (`https://secure.example.com`) and I have one GA profile created for `http://example.com`.

Now i want to track the **https** sub-domain, if i use the same code generated for **http site**, will that track both domains?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The same code will work for both protocols.